# How to switch to an old revision of the entire project?

Tags: version-control, cvs, revision-history

For what I know, `CVS` is not like `git` and `svn` that you can switch back to an older version of an entire repo code.

The best I tried is I checkout a date (some days ago), using Eclipse. But it checked out a **very old** version. I'm sure to have inserted the correct date.

Comment: Is it on the main branch HEAD, or is it on another branch? Have you tried it on the command line and if so what command did you use? If not, I'd suggest trying that. `cvs checkout -D<date> <rest of your options>` . Note that you should not have a space after `-D`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return to an old version of the entire repo code by running the following command from the root directory of your repo:

```
cvs update -r <TAG name>
```

where `TAG name` is the name of a TAG which was previously created on the entire repo using:

```
cvs tag -F <TAG name>
```

In `cvs`, a TAG is a list of files and their `cvs` revision. So using the `tag` command creates that list, and using the `update` command (with `-r` switch) is asking to return to the same file revisions which existed when tag was created.

One more important note, to return to the latest revision (head) of all files in you repo, use:

```
cvs update -A
```

Comment: I don't have a tag for that commit

Comment: How about using a date, what command format did you use? Try:
`cvs update -D "2001-09-14 23:59:59 GMT"`